# manage setState based on length before adding to it

Tags: reactjs

I essentially have a state with type array that will have a desired max limit in it, lets say a limit of 5 elements in the array.

Adding to the state with elements can come slowly, or just at quick succession.

The issue, that I'm aware of doing something like this won't work:

```
if (data.length < DATA_LIMIT) {
  setData((s) => [...s, newData])
} else {
  // add to another array and pop off once array is less then limit
}
```

...due to the fact that `useState` is asynchronous. So how can I reliable monitor when the data is added without causing many rerenders within useEffect?

I'm not sure how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move your condition into the update callback and if it is too long just return the previous state:

```js
setData((s) => {
  if (s.length < DATA_LIMIT) {
    return [...s, newData];
  } else {
    return s;
  }
});
```

This way the length you are checking will always be up-to-date.

Below is a running example where it tries to increment in sets of 2, and you can see that it prevents going over the sample limit of 3.

```js
const { useState } = React;

const DATA_LIMIT = 3;

const Example = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  
  function handleClick() {
    updateState();
    updateState();
  }
  
  function updateState() {
    setData((s) => {
      if (s.length < DATA_LIMIT) {
        return [...s, 'item'];
      } else {
        return s;
      }
    });
  }
   
  console.log("data ", data);
   
  return <button onClick={handleClick}>Increment</button>
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```